# Access a WCF service, hosted in a Windows Service with mobile device

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am trying to access a WCF service hosted in a windows service with an android device. I've gone through the [xamarin tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/walkthrough_working_with_WCF/) for consuming an WCF service hosted in IIS, and through an [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/653493/WCF-Hosting-with-Windows-Service#_articleTop) for hosting WCF with a Windows service and access it with a console application.
Up to now, I've tried to cross those two solutions, but nothing worked. 
All I can get out of that is, that a `FileNotFoundException` is caught, saying that is misses the `ServiceReferences.ClientConfig` in the `/` directory. So I've tried to embed this file (which was created by the SLsvcUtil), but nothing worked.
Everytime I call `Open`, or `AddAsync` or something I get an ReferenceNullException.
So, whats the correct way to connect to an WindowsService hosted WCF service with an mobile device?

Comment: If you are hosting using `localHost` and using an android emulator you wont be able to contact it. You will have to host your service for real. Just saying

Comment: If i say mobile device, i am talking about a physical mobile device. Service is hosted with the local IP of my PC. This service is not meant to be hosted on the internet, just inside of a lokal network. And yes, the device is located in the same network.

Comment: I'm not sure even physical devices can contact LocalHost. You will have to host it on your local network properly, not localhost

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i got it to work properly:

I worked myself through the tutorial on CodeProject again. After that, I created an additional android project and added the poxy class. As I was unable to use the App.Config file, I defined the binding in code. The async methods will fail for some reason, but packing them into a Task.Run and awaiting that just works fine as well:

```
void InitializeServiceConnection()
{
    EndpointAddress ea = new EndpointAddress("http://x.x.x.x:9001/CalcService");
    BasicHttpBinding bhttpb = new BasicHttpBinding()
    {
        Security = new BasicHttpSecurity()
          {
              Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None,
              Transport = new HttpTransportSecurity()
                {
                    ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None,
                    ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None
                }
           },
        BypassProxyOnLocal = true
    };
    objCalcClient2 = new CalcServiceClient(bhttpb, ea);
}

    async void DoStuff()
    {
        dblResult = await Task.Run<double>(delegate { return objCalcClient2.Add(dblX, dblY); });
        WriteLine(string.Format("Calling Add >>  X : {0:F2}  Y : {1:F2} Result : {2:F2}", dblX, dblY, dblResult));
        dblResult = await Task.Run<double>(() => { return objCalcClient2.Subtract(dblX, dblY); });
        WriteLine(string.Format("Calling Sub >>  X : {0:F2}  Y : {1:F2} Result : {2:F2}", dblX, dblY, dblResult));
        dblResult = await Task.Run<double>(() => { return objCalcClient2.Multiply(dblX, dblY); });
        WriteLine(string.Format("Calling Mul >>  X : {0:F2}  Y : {1:F2} Result : {2:F2}", dblX, dblY, dblResult));
        dblResult = await Task.Run<double>(() => { return objCalcClient2.Divide(dblX, dblY); });
        WriteLine(string.Format("Calling Div >>  X : {0:F2}  Y : {1:F2} Result : {2:F2}", dblX, dblY, dblResult));
    }

    void WriteLine(string Text)
    {
        tvConsole.Text += System.Environment.NewLine + Text;
        tvConsole.Invalidate();
    }
```

I am not sure if I have to populate the Transport property to get an unsecured and unauthenticated connection but it worked. Thats all I want.

But the best thing is, this also works in an Xamarin.Forms project as part of the PCL-Library.

```
private void Initialize()
    {
        EndpointAddress ea = new EndpointAddress("http://x.x.x.x:9001/CalcService");
        BasicHttpBinding bhttpb = new BasicHttpBinding();
        bhttpb.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None;
        objCalcClient2 = new CalcServiceClient(bhttpb, ea);
    }

    public async void DoStuff()
    {
        dblResult = await Task.Run<double>(delegate { return objCalcClient2.Add(dblX, dblY); });
        WriteLine(string.Format("Calling Add >>  X : {0:F2}  Y : {1:F2} Result : {2:F2}", dblX, dblY, dblResult));
        dblResult = await Task.Run<double>(() => { return objCalcClient2.Subtract(dblX, dblY); });
        WriteLine(string.Format("Calling Sub >>  X : {0:F2}  Y : {1:F2} Result : {2:F2}", dblX, dblY, dblResult));
        dblResult = await Task.Run<double>(() => { return objCalcClient2.Multiply(dblX, dblY); });
        WriteLine(string.Format("Calling Mul >>  X : {0:F2}  Y : {1:F2} Result : {2:F2}", dblX, dblY, dblResult));
        dblResult = await Task.Run<double>(() => { return objCalcClient2.Divide(dblX, dblY); });
        WriteLine(string.Format("Calling Div >>  X : {0:F2}  Y : {1:F2} Result : {2:F2}", dblX, dblY, dblResult));
    }

    void WriteLine(string Text)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(Text);
    }
```

I thought I had to implement this for each device, but no, WCF can be shared too.